# Wordpress redirection to get url friendly

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I want to get url friendly for pass data to page from other page.
I explain :

I have on i classic wordpress page, url like it : ( example.com/agent/name_agent )
it's url build dynamically. ( get_permalink($id_page_agent) . $name_agent )

In my loop-agent.php , i can manage $_GET['agent_name'] to make a filter.

I need to build redirection example.com/agent/name_agent > example.com/agent/?agent_name=name_agent

I don't know if you understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then trying implement something for you, I would recommend you to read these two nice articles about Rewrite API: [The Rewrite API: The Basics](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/) and [The Rewrite API: Post Types & Taxonomies](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies/). Spare no effort to read these articles and it will help you a lot in a future.